# Show_as_action_with_text  работает не всегда

Tags: actionbar, android, android-menu

Доброго времени суток.
Создаю динамическое меню

```
MenuItem menuItem = menu.add(0, DISLIKE, 0, slike).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_bad);

MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(menuItem, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS | MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT);
```

Проблема в том что текст отображается не всегда ─ на просторах буржуйского нета нашел

> Text is only shown in certain configurations (e.g. in landscape, or on tablets). This is not a bug.

только на практике получается что на одном и том же девайсе, не меняя ориентации экрана текст то показывается, то нет.

Comment: Попробовать у menu вызвать invalidate?